# angularjs: check for an id exists in an array r not

Tags: javascript

```js
var vm = this;
vm.usableDeposits = [];
for (var i = 0; i < billableChargeCodes.length; i++) {
  var deposits = usableDeposits.filter(function(ud) {
    return ud.billinggroupuid == billableChargeCodes[i].billinggroupuid ||
      ud.billinggroupuid == billableChargeCodes[i].billingsubgroupuid ||
      ud.departmentuid == billableChargeCodes[i].departmentuid ||
      !ud.entypeuid ||
      ud.entypeuid == entypeuid
  })
  for (var i = 0; i < deposits.length; i++) {
    var depositid = deposits[i]._id;
```

first time, `vm.usableDeposits[]` is empty. I have to check `deposits[i]._id` exists in `vm.usableDeposits[]` or not. How to check `vm.usableDeposits[]` empty array _id with `deposits[i]._id`? if id  not exists in `vm.usableDeposits[]`, then i want to push the element into `vm.usableDeposits[]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use the [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) operator in JavaScript to check if a value exists in the array or not. It returns `-1` if the value is not in the array,  else, it returns the index of the element in the `array`.

The syntax goes like this -

```
if(myArray.indexOf(value) !== -1) {
    // do this
} else {
    // do that
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is this correct?    if(vm.usableDeposits.indexOf(deposits[i]._id) !== -1) {
                                vm.usableDeposits.push(deposits[i]);
                            }

Answer (score 0):

You can use .some

```
deposits.some(o=> vm.usableDeposits.indexOf(o.id))
```

to check if the ID in `deposits` array is in `vm.usableDeposits`. `.some` will return `true` if condition is true and false otherwise

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.findIndexInData = function(data, property, value) {
    var result = -1;
        if((!!data) && (!!property) && (!!value)){
            data.some(function (item, i) {
                if (item[property] === value) {
                    result = i;
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
    return result;
  }
```

Pass on the array as the First Element. Property as second element and value you are looking in that array.

Example:

```
array = [{id:"1234",name:"abc"}, {id:"4567",name"xyz"}]
```

So you need to call:

```
index = $scope.findIndexInData(array , 'id' , 4567)
```